# Sending email with check box formula gives me range error using script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

Here is the script for this it keeps saying range undefined and I cant figure it out

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // this script is installed as an installable onEdit trigger
  /*
   if the checkbox is ticked, send this email
   Email subject= BatchTower Issue
   Email message= contents below
   Timestamp: 01/06/2020 + times
   What Locked Up:BatchComputer/Laptop
   Program Locked up:Red Rhino/Black Rhino
   Error:
   Reason:
   Batch in Progress: yes/no
   Corrective Action:
  */

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // the checkboxes are in column I
  var eCol=9;

  // get the key event obvjects
  var erange = e.range();
  var eRow = erange.rowStart();
  var eCol = erange.columnStart();
  var eSheet = erange.getSheet().getName();
  var eVal = e.value;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The edited sheet is "+eSheet);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The edited row is "+eRow);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The edited Column is "+eCol);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The edited_value = "+eVal)
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); DEBUG

  // apply logic to detect if check box is ticked.
  if (eSheet == sheetname && eCol== eCol && eVal == "TRUE" ){
    // the stars are in alignedment, send the email
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: send the email");

    // get the data column A to column H
    var data = sheet.getRange(eRow, 1, 1, 20).getValues();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range is "+sheet.getRange(eRow, 1, 1, 20).getA1Notation())

    // get the email address
    var emailaddress= sheet.getRange(S1).getValue();
    Logger.log("the email is "+emailaddress);

    // get the message information
    var timestamp = data[0][1];
    var whatlockedup = data[0][3];
    var programlockup = data[0][4];
    var error = data[0][5];
    var reason = data[0][6];
    var batch = data[0][7];
    var correctiveaction = data[0][8];

    var emailSubject = "BatchTower Issue";

    var emailMessage= "Timestamp: "+timestamp+"\n"+
      "What Locked Up: "+whatlockedup+"\n"+
      "Program Locked up: "+programlockup+"\n"+
      "Error: "+error+"\n"+
      "Reason: "+reason+"\n"+
      "Batch in Progress: "+batch;
      "Corrective Action: "+correctiveaction+"\n"+
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the message is:"+emailMessage);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, emailSubject, emailMessage);

  }else{
    // something doesn't match
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: do not send the email");

  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The code above is mangled, so consider [reformatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help) it. Also consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data and with the script attached.

Comment: Please add the textual error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by replacing

`var eSheet = erange.getSheet().getName()`

...with:

`var eSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()`

...and correcting other similar errors in the code.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).